# C++11 for loop with cin>>buff;

Tags: string, c++11, for-loop

i recently came across this code:

```
int count=0;
for(std::string buf; std::cin>>buf;) {
    count++;
}
std::cout << count;
```

1. My doubt is what does this code do?
2. how is the `cin>>buf` thing working in the condition part?
3. isn't it going in an infinite loop?
4. trying to write it in c++11 give me error for `String`, is `std::string` different from `String`, if so, then which header do i need for `String`

Comment: There is no predefined `String` in any version of C++.

Comment: ok, lets consider i use std::string. How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assuming `String` is valid when this compiles and runs, it will construct once, read as many times as it can, and count along the way.  `count` is rather meaningless, though, since it is not initialized.
2. `cin>>buf` is the read, of course, but also a test, and as it reads successfully, the expression evaluates to true, so the loop is iterated again.
3. It could go into an infinite loop, unless the user enters EOF.
4. pmr is right about the class:  `String` is different from `string`.  If you want to use the loop, the most straightforward solution is to just change it to `std::string`.